# Repeat a row multiple times in a gridview

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I have a `Gridview` with a column called `Quantity`. Each product has it own quantity. I need to show as many rows as the quantity says.

For example, if I have

```
Car | 4 | $ 20
```

I need to show 4 rows like

```
Car | 1 | 20
```

I can't find a way of doing this. I am using linq to retrieve the data from the database and that is the `DataSource` of my `Gridview`.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the linq [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method. Assuming you have a linq source like this (trivial example)

```
var result = 
    from r in db.SourceTable
    select new { r.Name, r.Quantity, r.Price };
```

Add this to the query

```
var result = 
    from r in db.SourceTable
    from s in Enumerable.Range(1, record.Quantity)
    select new { r.Name, 1, r.Price };
```

However, this is probably not supported by entity framework (and probably not in any other ORM) so you may need to call `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` first.

Comment: You almost never need to call `ToList()` unless you need indexed access. `AsEnumerable` will accomplish the same thing without wasting memory and forcing iteration of the entire sequence.